# The parameter is incorrect in TextIOWrapper creating logger with cogs

Tags: python, logging, discord, discord.py

I am trying to have an automated logging system that put all send and deleted messages but every once in a while I get this error:

```
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect
```

It's easy enough to restart the bot but since this is an automated system once this error hits it completely shuts down and falls into this loop printing this error

Here is my code:

```
from discord.ext import commands


# https://youtu.be/BoVOzm1uhUA
class Logger(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, c):
        if(c.guild):
            if c.guild.name == "Server Name":
                if c.author.bot == True:
                    try:
                        print(f"Bot: {c.author} said --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}")
                    except OSError:
                        print('An error occurred')
                        pass
                else:
                    try:
                        print(f"User: {c.author} said --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}")
                    except OSError:
                        print('An error occurred')
                        pass
            elif c.guild.name == "Server 2 Name":
                if c.author.bot == True:
                    try:
                        print(f"Bot: {c.author} said --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}")
                    except OSError:
                        print('An error occurred')
                        pass

                else:
                    try:
                        print(f"User: {c.author} said --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}")
                    except OSError:
                        print('An error occurred')
                        pass

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_delete(self, c):
        if(c.guild):
            if c.guild.name == "Server Name":
                if c.author.bot == True:
                    print(f"Bot: {c.author} deleted --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}")
                    pass
                else:
                    print(f"User: {c.author} deleted --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}")
                    pass
            elif c.guild.name == "Server 2 Name":
                if c.author.bot == True:
                    print(f"Bot: {c.author} deleted --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}")
                    pass
                else:
                    print(f"User: {c.author} deleted --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}")
                    pass

#print(f"{c.created_at} || Bot: {c.author} deleted --- {c.clean_content} --- in #{c.channel.name}");

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Logger(bot))
```

As you can see I already tried to fix this error but it didn't work
Any help is much appreciated. This bug is driving me nuts

Comment: Have you tried removing the `self` argument from your function? (this worked on another answer I wrote a while ago)

Comment: no, the bot does not work like that since this logger is in a cog

Comment: Can you edit your question to give us the full error text?

Comment: this is it, it just loops through this same error

Comment: Feels like it's just a encoding issue, as you or your users probably use non-english letters, resulting in `utf-8` not being able to encode/decode it properly and thus crashes.